# Видимость github репозитория в поисковике

Tags: github

Могу ли я сделать гитхаб репозиторий открытым только в случае перехода на мой профиль?
Иными словами, закрыть видимость частей моего кода/текста из поисковика?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, потому что в этом просто нет смысла

Comment: Вкратце - нет. Только два вариант: либо все видно, либо ничего не видно (если доступа нет).